# How to read the following table correctly with pd.read_csv in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, mismatch

I read a file as

```
  1  [ 1s 1/2-1/2]+    0.83   -66.379    -1.0000000     
  2  [ 1s 1/2 1/2]+    0.83   -66.379    -1.0000000
  3  [ 1s 1/2-1/2]+    0.82   -61.930     1.0000000
  4  [ 1s 1/2 1/2]+    0.82   -61.930     1.0000000
  5  [ 1p 3/2-1/2]-    0.73   -40.210    -1.0000000
  6  [ 1p 3/2 1/2]-    0.77   -40.210    -1.0000000
  7  [ 1p 3/2-3/2]-    0.76   -40.210    -1.0000000
  8  [ 1p 3/2 3/2]-    0.64   -40.210    -1.0000000
```

in the following way:

```
spe=pd.read_csv("spe.dat",delimiter='s\+',skiprows=[0,1])
spe.columns=['index','label','weight','ee','tz']
```

I got the error message:

```
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1 elements, new values have 5 elements
```

I realized that the second column such as `'[ 1s 1/2-1/2]+'` was read as three columns. Is there any way to read the whole `'[ 1s 1/2-1/2]+'` as one column? Thanks.

Comment: Is your data in a fixed width format?  If so, use [`pd.read_fwf()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html).

Comment: Thanks. It works.

Comment: With your suggestion, I was able to read the file correctly with some additional efforts.                               spe=pd.read_fwf("spe.dat",skiprows=[0,1]) 
spe.columns=['index','label1','label2','label3','weight','ee','tz']                            
label=spe.label1 + spe.label2 + spe.label3
droplist=['label1','label2','label3']
spe.drop(droplist, axis=1, inplace=True)
spe['label']=label

Answer (score 0):

You are not separating the columns properly when you read the DataFrame. I recommend reading [the Python regex tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) to understand how to use regular expressions for the separator.

```
columns = ['index','label','weight','ee','tz']
pd.read_csv('spe.dat', sep='\s{2,}', names=columns, index_col=0, skiprows=[0, 1])
```

returns

```
                label  weight      ee   tz
index                                     
1      [ 1s 1/2-1/2]+    0.83 -66.379 -1.0
2      [ 1s 1/2 1/2]+    0.83 -66.379 -1.0
3      [ 1s 1/2-1/2]+    0.82 -61.930  1.0
4      [ 1s 1/2 1/2]+    0.82 -61.930  1.0
5      [ 1p 3/2-1/2]-    0.73 -40.210 -1.0
6      [ 1p 3/2 1/2]-    0.77 -40.210 -1.0
7      [ 1p 3/2-3/2]-    0.76 -40.210 -1.0
8      [ 1p 3/2 3/2]-    0.64 -40.210 -1.0
```

Comment: This is good, but I'm a bit concerned if the index gets to two or three digits whether that two or more spaces rule will hold up.  If it's a fixed-width file it may not.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Agreed but I would assume so... Otherwise once the index got to 4 digits it would be overwriting the first column!

Comment: Or perhaps six digits.  When I added formatting to the original text question the each row started space-space-digit-space-space-bracket.  So maybe there was five spaces if the digit was centered.

Comment: Thanks. It works better. Could you explain the meaning of "sep='\s{2,}' "? Why using it makes it work?

Comment: @JimmyYao Checkout the regex tutorial I linked in the answer. The first two sections address that question better than I can in a comment.

Comment: @JimmyYao Please [mark an answer as correct](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it resolved your question. This helps us keep track of which questions are left to be answered.